# Is it true that $V^{\otimes k}=S^k (V)\oplus \Lambda^k V$ for $\dim V\ge 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

I was trying to show that $V^{\otimes 2}=S^2(V)\oplus \Lambda^2V$ and this is what I came up with. Obviously $S^2(V)\oplus \Lambda^2V\subset V^{\otimes 2}$. Now take $a\in V^{\otimes 2}$.Let $\dim V=n$ and let the basis of $V^{\otimes 2}$ be $\{v_i\otimes v_j\}_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$. Then we can write $a=\sum\frac{1}{2}a_{ij}((v_i\otimes v_j)+(v_j\otimes v_i))+\sum\frac{1}{2}a_{ij}((v_i\otimes v_j)-(v_j\otimes v_i))$ and the first one is in $S^2(V)$ and the other in $\Lambda^2V$.
Also, we see that intersection of $S^2(V)$ and $\Lambda^2V$ is just $\{0\}$.

I hope what I did was right. My question is: Can we say that $V^{\otimes k}=S^k (V)\oplus \Lambda^k V$ for say $k=3$ or higher? My intuition says no because I can't write any element in $V^{\otimes k}$ into two pieces like I did before.

Comment: For higher $k$, you have to consider tensors with some symmetric pairs, some antisymmetric pairs. Young tableaux enumerate you all the ways you can do this, so those will give the terms on the right hand side of your isomorphism.

Comment: @ziggurism, sorry I don't know anything about Young tableaux.

Comment: No need to apologize...

Comment: I might add that a nice way to see that your isomorphism does not work is that $V^{\otimes k}$ is $n^k$ dimensional, while $S^k(V)\oplus \Lambda^k(V)$ is $n(n-1)/2+n+n(n-1)/2=n^2$ dimensional. For $k\neq 2$ those are obviously distinct.

Comment: @ziggurism, thank you! I think that works. I'd be still happy to see the argument using Young tableaux.

Comment: Yeah I mean a proper explanation of how to use young tableaux would be great, but I don't know how to do the diagrams on here. So I'll just give a little more detail. You took all the rank two tensors and split them into those who get a minus sign under exchange of indices 1 and 2, and those who are invariant. If there are three indices, consider those tensors who pick up a minus sign under exchange of 1 and 2, but not 2 and 3, etc. these tensors are not in $\Lambda^3$ or $S^3$, but do need to be counted.

Comment: Young tableaux help you organize all the different ways you can group your indices into antisymmetrized subgroups. You list all the partitions of $k$, draw a sequence of boxes of length each summand and stack them in ascending order, and label each box with a number from 1 to $k$. The resulting diagram corresponds to tensors antisymmetric under exchange of rows, and symmetric under exchange of columns. The rules of young tableaux make it easy to list all possible combinations, and this gives a decomposition of the space of all tensors into irreps of the symmetric group on $k$ letters.

Comment: My explanation is hard to follow. I think it's better to see some explicit examples.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through this.

Comment: Let's start with $k=2$. The partitions are 2=2 and 2=1+1. Out of the first partition, we can make a Young diagram with one row of length two. We number the boxes (this is the Young tableau) and construct the Young symmetrizer by taking the product of the sum of row-preserving permutations with the alternating sum of column-preserving permutations. In the tableau 1 2, only identity preserves columns, so our symmetrizer is 1+(12). The image of this map is $S^2(V)$. For the tableau 1 CRLF 2, only the identity preserves rows, our symmetrizer is 1-(12), whose image is $\Lambda^2(V)$.

Comment: Now $k=3$. The partitions are 3=1+1+1, 3=2+1, and 3=3. So for tableau 1 2 3, symmetrizer is 1+(123)+(132)-(12)-(23)-(13), which spans $\Lambda^3(V)$. For tableau 1 CRLF 2 CRLF 3, symmetrizer is 1+(12)+(23)+(13)+(123)+(132), which spans $S^3(V)$.

Comment: And from partition 3=2+1, we have tableau 1 2 CRLF 3. The permutations 1 and (12) preserve rows, whereas 1 and (13) preserve columns. So symmetrizer is (1-(13))(1+(12))=1-(13)+(12)-(123). The span is tensors who are symmetric with respect to exchange of first two indices, as well as some other symmetries for other permutations. I don't believe this space admits a description in terms of the symmetric power and alternating power functors. It's a Specht module and is usually just labeled by its Young tableau. You should have an isomorphism of the required form if you include these other tensors.